# how to use $_REQUEST for an array in HTML

Tags: php

I'm generating a form with inputs like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="# of patients" name="txt[1]" class=" form-control " />
<input type="text" placeholder="# of patients" name="txt[2]" class=" form-control " />
<input type="text" placeholder="# of patients" name="txt[3]" class=" form-control " />
<input type="text" placeholder="# of patients" name="txt[4]" class=" form-control " />
```

Now I want to get the values written in these fields using PHP. I'm using:

```
for($i = $maxi->max_id; $i<=$mani->min_id ; $i++) {
    $Query = "UPDATE general table set number_of_patient='".$_REQUEST['txt[$i]']."'" ; 
    mysql_query($Query);
}
```

But it does not work and says "Undefined index".
Kindly solve me for this.
Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `mysql_*` functions. It's deprecated and will be removed from PHP.

You are using `$_REQUEST['txt[$i]']` and `PHP` tells you truth about `txt[$i]` index. It simply doesn't exist.

To access your data you have to use `$_POST['txt']`. There will be array with sent data. Don't forget to filter user input!

Comment: the same error is still there.
I need to actually store  the data received from the fields dynamically generated on by one in the database.

Comment: So try to debug and check what you can find in `$_POST` array (eg. using `var_dump`). And update your code.

Comment: $min = $mani->min_id;
     $max = $maxi->max_id;
     $number = $_POST['txt'];
     for($i = $min; $i<=$max ; $i++) 
      {  
   
   
   $Query ="INSERT INTO patients(d_id,number) VALUES($i,$number )"; this is the code

Comment: It's terrible.. You are not even filtering data from user. Also use `var_dump` on `$_POST` and you'll see what is wrong here.